# Java Program - Write a program that calculates the area of a circle using a method called circleArea

Tags: java

This is the code that I came up with so far:

```
package circlearea2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleArea2
{   
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      double a;
      double c;
      System.out.println("Enter the radius: ");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      a = scan.nextDouble();

      c = areaCalc(a);
      System.out.println("Circle Area is: " + c);
   }

   public static double areaCalc(double n1) {
      double min;

      min = (n1 * n1 * 3.14);

      return min; 
   }
}
```

The problem is fixed. Thanks everyone! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The method areaCalc takes an integer (why is that?) but you're giving it a double. its warning you that your answer is highly likely to end up being wrong as a result (so it doesn't let you compile)

Comment: Also, why do you cast the 'min' to an integer?

Comment: I cast min to an integer because that was the only way that the code would compile. But I did change the parameters to double, and I'll update the code.

*EDIT : It works now, thanks!

Comment: Whenever you cast follow this thought process "Java says what I'm doing is probably a bad idea, when I cast I promise java I really do know what I'm doing and it'll be fine". Casting is only very occasionally the correct thing to do. Awesome that it works now. importantly do you understand why it didn't work before and does now? And what would have have happen if java had "just let it compile?

Comment: Yup. Java (funny how we're referring to Java as if it is a person) only wanted me to cast it as an integer because it felt that it would make more sense that way, even though it wasn't required. I did, however, need to put parentheses around my equation though, but all in all, the code works, I understand, and that is what's most important. Thanks for all your help Mr. Tingle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `areaCalc()` should be of type `double`, but it is `int`. When you pass a `double`, it must be converted to an `int`, but that will cause a loss of precision and the language requires you to make an explicit cast if you attempt that.

If you code your method like this:

```
public static double areaCalc(double n1) { ... }
```

You'll have no problem (and it will make more sense too).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `areaCalc` takes an int, but you're providing a double. Change it to take a double:

```
public static double areaCalc(double n) {
    return n * n * 3.14;
}
```

For more accuracy, you can use `Math.PI`.

```
public static double areaCalc(double n) {
    return n * n * Math.PI;
}
```